# Unresolved Dependencies: Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

After importing an old project (2015) to Android Studio. I got some Gradle's issue, so I made changes: upgraded the Gradle plugin to 4.4, changed build.gradle, and also the dependencies from compile to implementation. But I couldn't find any solution at all.

Please check the following:

The Dependencies In build.gradle:

![The Dependencies In build.gradle][1]

Build.Gradle:

![Build.Gradle][2]

Build.Gradle (Project):

![Build.Gradle (Project)][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your app `build.gradle`

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

then in your Project `build.gradle`

under all projects add maven like below.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the latest dependency, which is as below?

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies here
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try latest version of this library. It is compiling fine, just checked:-

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies here
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
}
```